# Streaming tracks from a private playlist with secret_token generates 404

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Streaming a private track from a private playlist used to work fine using it's parent playlist's secret token. It now generates a 404. This started happening Dec. 7, 2016. I'm using SoundCloud's js sdk v3.1.2

To clarify, I'm using the track's `stream_url` returned from the **`playlists/`** endpoint. In this case the playlist's secret_token is `s-6AMBa`, as well as each track's `secret_token` in that playlist. Code below is how I'm streaming one track from that private playlist.

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: [clientid],
    redirect_uri: [redirect_uri]
});
SC.stream('/tracks/296005694', 's-6AMBa').then(function(data) {
    data.play();
}).catch(function(error) {
    alert('Error! ' + error.message);
});
```

The error:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/296005694?secret_token=s-6AMBa&format=json&client_id=[clientid]
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

That link in the error produces a 404,  but this slight adjustment (adding `/stream` after the track id), resolves correctly.

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/296005694/stream?secret_token=s-6AMBa&format=json&client_id=[clientid]`
```

Like I mentioned, this system has been working for years for me and only recently started generating 404s. Is anyone else having this problem? Did anything recently change in regards to playlist secret tokens?

Comment: Is it working with the uri defined in the way as var uri = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/210702559.json?' +
secretToken + '&' + clientId; ?

Comment: @pritishvaidya No. That also generates a 404.

Comment: did you share the private list or the playlist?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify what you're asking? I store the `secret_token` during an authenticated session and am attempting to show that playlist to an un-authenticated user.

Comment: I mean to say if you used the share option,by clicking the link below the waveform so that anyone with the secret link can access your track

Comment: No, there is no step when the authenticated user clicks the share button.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists) if you want to return the *stream* of the audio through an *endpoint* of a *playlist* then the appropriate **URI** for it is

```
[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/282919801/stream?secret_token=s-EqJoD&client_id=[clientid]"]
```

and to access the *endpoint* of the single track then the appropriate **URI** for it is

```
[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/276344823/stream?secret_token=s-EqJod&client_id=[clientid]"]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate how that would work using `SC.stream()`?

Comment: if you want to get a stream to an endpoint of a playlist track then simply use the URI in the format https://api.soundcloud.com/playlist/276344823/stream?secret_token=s-EqJod&c